# Trying to Call MYSQL Procedure to return int value based on Condition to php

Tags: php, mysql, integer, return, procedure

I'm trying to create an SQL procedure where is returns a specified value from the members table.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `qrgdev`.`ConfirmMember` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `qrgdev`.`ConfirmMember` (
  check_Username varchar(45),
  check_Password varchar(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE intcheckId INTEGER(1);
  DECLARE intAccessLevel INTEGER(1) DEFAULT 0;

  SELECT id INTO intCheckId FROM members WHERE Username=Check_Username;

  IF (intCheckId=0)

    SELECT AccessLevel INTO intAccessLevel FROM members WHERE passwrd=check_Password;

  ELSE

    IF (intCheckId>0) THEN
      Update members
      Set LastSignIn=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      Where ID=intCheckId;
      SELECT AccessLevel INTO intAccessLevel FROM members WHERE id=intCheckId;
    ELSE
      Insert into members
        (ID, Username, Administrator, Passwrd, LastSignIn)
      values
        (null, check_Username, 0, null, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    END IF;

  END IF;

  RETURN(intAccessLevel);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

so that i can have php set conditions based on that value

```
//...
$result = $mysqli->query("Call ConfirmMember($username,$password)");
//...
```

this started as a function before i learned that php cant call sql functions, its why it still hols return at the bottom and also get the point i want to return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create an SQL procedure where is returns a specified value

There's your biggest problem. Procedures do not return values. Functions return values. OTOH you can pass references to variables as arguments in both procedures and functions - and the procedure/function can change the value.

> this started as a function before i learned that php cant call sql functions

Who told you that? It's complete nonsense.

> $result = $mysqli->query("Call ConfirmMember($username,$password)");

I assume you've escaped and quoted those variables.

Change PROCEDURE to FUNCTION then invoke it as....

```
SELECT ConfirmMember($username,$password)
```

Comment: After changing to function and putting in the returns, now it doesnt like my select statment

`Script line: 4 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT AccessLevel INTO intAccessLevel FROM members WHERE passwr' at line 12`